# Mysqldump Errcode: 24 - Too many open files

Tags: mysqldump

When I attempt to back up one of my database I am getting the following error.

```
mysqldump: Got error: 23: Out of resources when opening file './mysql_db/table_name.MYD' (Errcode: 24 - Too many open files) when using LOCK TABLES
```

I have attempted to increase the number of allowed open files with the following in `/etc/security/limits.conf`

```
* hard nofile 165535
* soft nofile 165535
```

I am now seeing

```
ulimit -n
165535
ulimit -Hn
165535
ulimit -Sn
165535
```

I saw some suggestion to changing these lines in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service`

```
LimitNOFILE=10000
LimitMEMLOCK=10000
```

but that file does not exist at that location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was suggested to me in another forum to check out this post.

https://serverfault.com/questions/104618/out-of-resources-for-mysqldump/104686

in the end I added `--single-transaction` to the mysqldump command like the following

```
mysqldump --user user_name --password=my_password --single-transaction database_to_export > ~/sql_file.sql
```

I noticed in a comment on the referenced post if `--single-transaction` gives problems using `--lock-all-tables` might be helpful for someone as well.